# How to run delegate asynchronously using task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, thread-safety, task

I am trying to print "Loading ..." every second while the delegate is running asynchronously

`indicator` returns `true` to indicate that the process has ended and thus end the while loop

```cs
public delegate bool MyDelegate();
public static async Task Loading(MyDelegate indicator)
{
    bool AsyncMethodFinished = false;
    while (!AsyncMethodFinished)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading...");
        AsyncMethodFinished = await Task.Run(()=>indicator.Invoke());
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

for example,
if "indicator" takes 10 seconds to finish,
the output should be 10 times "Loading...", but I can't get it.

I am trying to learn how to use Task with these types of exercises but I cannot understand how it works, could you help me to achieve it?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd say perhaps don't try and teach yourself this stuff in a console app; console apps don't obviously "do anything else" while the task is running so it's hard to see the asyncrony. The idea of async code is that the thread that inits the work is allowed to go and do something else while the work completes, and the await is a mechanism to write async code like sync code (which is easier to understand) because it allows you to define points by which you need the result from the async work

Comment: If you do want to persist with it, don't put your Task.Run inside the loop, put it before, and don't await it; await makes your code stop (and the thread that was doing it is freed up to go and do something else) at that point and wait for the awaited Task to finish, which means your loop won't. You'll also need to figure out a way to make your task set the boolean that the loop is checking when it's done. All in I don't think, as an example, it's very helpful - did you get it from a webpage?

Comment: What's the intended usage of the `indicator` delegate? Do you want to invoke it every second, or only once?

Comment: @HéctorReyna Do you want to fire off your `indicator` asynchronously then print `Loading` in each and every second while it is running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this example makes thing clearer for you:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var @do = new Do();
            Task.Run(() => @do.DoSomthing());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main things in thread=>" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    public class Do
    {
        public async Task<bool> DoSomthing()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Doing Something in thread=>" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                await IOAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
        protected async Task IOAsync()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Work is too much in Thread=> " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await Task.Delay(250);
        }
    }
}
```

you have the main thread in your app, then you start some task that does some async operation within itself, and each operation is done in a separated thread

doing things like this will maximize utilization of CPU if done correctly and long-run tasks will never block the main thread.

the DoSomthing() method will take 2500ms to complete while the main operation only takes 1000ms so you will see how console is written, after 4 or 5 ticks in DoSomething(), the main will finish.

you can play with wait and delay numbers and for iteration to have a better view of things.

if you see the output you notice that the main thread id is always the same because it is running synchronously, but the job thread id is not guaranteed to be the same, which means the job is done by different threads.

------------- output ------------

Main things in thread=> 1

Doing Something in thread=> 4

Work is too much in Thread=> 4

Main things in thread=> 1

Main things in thread=> 1

Doing Something in thread=> 4

Work is too much in Thread=> 4

Main things in thread=> 1

Main things in thread=> 1

Doing Something in thread=> 4

Work is too much in Thread=> 4

Main things in thread=> 1

Main things in thread=> 1

Doing Something in thread=> 4

Work is too much in Thread=> 4

Main things in thread=> 1

Main things in thread=> 1

Main things in thread=> 1

Doing Something in thread=> 5

Work is too much in Thread=> 5

Doing Something in thread=> 5

Work is too much in Thread=> 5

Doing Something in thread=> 5

Work is too much in Thread=> 5

Doing Something in thread=> 5

Work is too much in Thread=> 5

Doing Something in thread=> 5

Work is too much in Thread=> 5

Doing Something in thread=> 6

Work is too much in Thread=> 6